# CSS flex: Third "card" showing beside the first two, I would like it below

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a pestering question I'd like an opinion on. I apologize if this has been answered. I have looked at similar questions, and tried the solutions, but I can't find the one that works for me.

I am working on a personal website right now and I have the home page how I like it, but I am trying to get the experience page to display correctly. Right now, I am trying to have 3-4 "cards" of content. The first two should show up in the main section side by side, and the third (and fourth if necessary) should show up below them as follows"

1 2

3 (centered, ideally the width of the first two items)

OR

1 2

3 4

Currently no matter what I try (clearing, changing the flex direction, etc) I am getting the following with the items squished together.

1 2 3...

I have attached my full styles.css (I apologize for the mess) so someone brighter than me can hopefully help me resolve the problem, and a snippet of my HTML so you can get an idea of how I am using this.

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Styles.css

```
/* Global Layout Set-up */
{ 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  background: #f7f5f0;
}
/* Link Styles */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0499ff;
}
a:hover {
  color: #6633ff;
}

/* Section Styles */

.main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-weight: 700;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav .name {
  display: none;
}
.nav li {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.nav a {
  transition: all .5s;
}
.nav a:hover {
  color: white
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background: url('images/realrocket5.jpg') no-repeat top center ;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
header {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
header .profile-image {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  transition: all .5s;
}
header .profile-image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(360deg);
}
.tag {
  background-color: #efefef;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: table;
  margin: 10px auto;
} 
.location {
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
}
.card {
  float: left;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.card-below{
  float: left;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px 40px 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.card:hover {
  border-color: #0399ff;
}

ul.skills {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.skills li {
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff9904;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.skills li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #0399ff;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 20px 0 40px 20px;
}

footer .copyright {
  top: -8px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: .75em;
}

footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a.social {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: all .25s;
}
a.twitter {
  background-image: url(images/twitter.svg);
}
a.linkedin {
  background-image: url(images/linkedin.svg);
}
a.github {
  background-image: url(images/github.svg);
}
a.social:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

/* Styles for larger screens */
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {

  .flex {
      display: flex;
      max-width: 1200px;
      justify-content: space-around;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  header {
    min-height: 450px;
  }

  .nav {
    max-width: 1200px;
  }

  .nav .name {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid #2204ba 3px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #222;
    margin-right: auto;
    margit-left: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0399ff;
  }

  .nav .navbar {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid #2204ba 3px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #222;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0399ff;
  }

  main {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }

  main p {
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }

  footer {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 40px auto;
  }

}

h3 {
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.card-title {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
<main class="flex">
  <div class="card">
    <h2 class="card-title">Card1</h2>
    <p>Stuff goes here, up to 500px wide</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h2 class="card-title">Card2</h2>
    <p>More stuff goes here up to 500px wide</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <h2 class="card-title">Card3</h2>
      <p>The problem card. This stuff needs to go below card one in its own card.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```

If I only use two cards per page they appear side by side correctly. When trying to add a third, it just goes beside the last card and I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it go below. Ideally, if using 3 cards the first two would be centered side by side, then the third would be centered below the same width as the first two cards combined. If a 4th card is used, I'd like it to basically be a square. Thank you so much for any input!!!!

Comment: Set a `flex-wrap:wrap` on the flex container?  Might need to set a max width on it too.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that! Admittedly its been a while since I've used CSS and I'm just now getting back into it, so a lot of this is new stuff for me.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! That fixed it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  background: gray;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

  
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  min-width: 75px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      Box One
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Box Two
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      Box Three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      Box One
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Box Two
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      Box Three
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Box Four
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't currently upvote this because this is a new account, but the solution is valid.

Comment: Perhaps you'll be able to in the future and also find value in the question again. Enjoy Stack!